# GNU Make variable "unexpected token"

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm working on a makefile environment for an FPGA team and I'm currently having issues with a macro.  I have it defined as shown for the TOOL_EXEC variable, but I'm getting an "unexpected token" error related to the double quotes and parenthesis.  If I put double double quotes the variable inflates without any quotations at all and yields no error, however our tool requires them to be in parenthesis. I need to pass the fully quoted parenthesis information, but the macro definition is giving me issues!

"syntax error near unexpected token `('   "

```
    Example call to tool: (This works fine)
    $ Tool --v v4.5 -odir . -verilog -vh "('name', 'propname', 'address', 'desc')" filename.rdl

    Desired Macro/variable: (not working)
    TOOL_EXEC = -odir . -verilog -vh "('name', 'propname', 'address', 'desc')"
```

Any Ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just escape every special character (e.g. quote, double quote or parenthesis) with a backslash:

```
TOOL_EXEC = -odir . -verilog -vh \"\(\'name\', \'propname\', \'address\', \'desc\'\)\"
```

Comment: This isn't what you want to do: it should not be necessary based on the command line example.

Comment: I'll have to try it when I get home, but I could have sworn I tried it.  I cant remember to be honest.  hah

Comment: omg ok so yeah I just had to escape the double quotes~  Thanks Beta and MadScientist for the replies!

Comment: It's not inflating correctly when it calls the tool! I have a make target that allows me to see whats in a variable by typing "$ make echo_TOOL_EXEC" which prints the variable contents correctly, but when the tool is actually being executed it tries to read in the backslashes which messes itup.

Comment: @MattCarlis: If you show us the command that invokes the tool (or better still, the whole rule) and what it actually does, we might have a chance of solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you set a variable in a makefile you use only the name of the variable, without the dollar sign, like this:

```
TOOL_EXEC = -odir . -verilog -vh "('name', 'propname', 'address', 'desc')"
```

If you write `${TOOL_EXEC}` then it will be expanded and the result of the expansion will be used as the variable name.  If it's not set, then it will resolve to:

```
 = -odir . -verilog -vh "('name', 'propname', 'address', 'desc')"
```

which is obviously not right.

Comment: ahhh!!  That was a typo in my post not a syntax error!  Sorry!

Comment: You should always cut and paste when asking questions, not retype.  That ensures what you ask about is exactly what you're using.  With computers even the smallest character change, even whitespace, can sometimes make all the difference.  Given the new example all we can say is that you haven't provided enough information.  The error is not where the variable is set, but rather where it is used in the makefile which you haven't shown us.  My suspicion is that you're quoting `$(TOOL_EXEC)` where it's used, which is not correct.

Comment: I cant paste source online!