# defining a variable in makefile with special characters -- -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)"

Tags: makefile, g++

I want to run the next line in a makefile:

```
g++  -O2 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -o "$@" "$<"
```

I want to define a variable that will contain all the flags:

```
FLAGS := -O2 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)"
```

and then use this variable instead of the hardcoded line:

```
g++ $(FLAGS) -o "$@" "$<"
```

however the last part of the above line (the quoted part) creates problems.
my question is how can I assign this line to a variable? I tried all kind of escape characters combinations but nothing seems to work.

thanks.

Comment: Does the command line shows correctly when running `make`? What's missing?

Comment: This question states that you should escape the double quotes with a backslash. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498327/gnu-make-variable-unexpected-token

Comment: @DidierTrosset when trying to escape the quotes with backslashes I get g++ -O2 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF\"\" -o "<file_name>.o" "../<file_name>.cpp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from the `FLAGS :=`. Indeed, using the `:=` operator to set the `FLAGS` variable instructs `make` to evaluate the value of the variable only once and *now*. However, at the time of the definition of `FLAGS`, variable `@` is not defined. It will only be defined within the rule that has the `g++` command. That's why it results in `-MF""`.

You should use `FLAGS=` (no column). Defined with the simple `=`, the `FLAGS` variable will only be evaluated when used, i.e. in the `g++` command line. At that place, the `$@` variable will be defined and valid.